# Can I use my macbook bluetooth as input to an android device

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth

I'm going to start off saying that this may be a stupid question, but I want to be certain.

Right now, I have a 7697 board
https://labs.mediatek.com/en/platform/linkit-7697

which has Bluetooth capabilities and is able to connect to an android device as a remote. The code I have written up has all the Bluetooth descriptors and button inputs that handles the navigation on the android device.

My goal is to port this over to mac without having to use this board. I would like to use Macbook's own Bluetooth capabilities and make it act as a Bluetooth device on the android device.

**Edit** Morrison pointed out that this was asked before 
[Virtual HID-keyboard for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197115/virtual-hid-keyboard-for-os-x)

Which only points to this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH215-TPXREF107

For me, I am still lost and need direction.

I also know there are programs that are out there like Typeeto
https://www.eltima.com/bluetooth-keyboard.html

I would like to know how these are made and how to develop my own. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual HID-keyboard for OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197115/virtual-hid-keyboard-for-os-x)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for the input. I actually saw this, but did not get any useful concrete information from it.